# cpan installer fails with “Cannot find pkg-config command.”

Tags: apt, 16.04, pkg-config

I am setting up a new Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)), and I want to install everything that I had installed on my previous server with Ubuntu 14.04. Among those the cpan module Text::QRCode:

Of course I start with:

```
root@myserver:~# apt update && apt full-upgrade
```

Then I try to install the module:

```
root@myserver:~# cpanm install Text::QRCode
```

I get this output:

```
install is up to date. (0.01)
--> Working on Text::QRCode
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/K/KU/KURIHARA/Text-QRCode-0.04.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Text-QRCode-0.04 ... N/A
! Configure failed for Text-QRCode-0.04. See /root/.cpanm/work/1471767672.8638/build.log for details.
```

So I view this logfile:

```
root@myserver:~# cat /root/.cpanm/work/1471767672.8638/build.log
```

and see this:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7040 on perl 5.022001 built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
Work directory is /root/.cpanm/work/1471767672.8638
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.15
You have /bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.28
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching install () on cpanmetadb ...
install is up to date. (0.01)
Searching Text::QRCode () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Text::QRCode
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/K/KU/KURIHARA/Text-QRCode-0.04.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Text-QRCode-0.04.tar.gz
Entering Text-QRCode-0.04
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.04_01)
Configuring Text-QRCode-0.04
Running Makefile.PL
Cannot determine perl version info from lib/Text/QRCode.pm
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Cannot find pkg-config command.
Specify it to PKG_CONFIG_BIN_PATH env variable if you have pkg-config cmd at Makefile.PL line 41.
-> N/A
-> FAIL Configure failed for Text-QRCode-0.04. See /root/.cpanm/work/1471767672.8638/build.log for details.
```

There is the line
**Cannot find pkg-config command.**

Obviously there is no pkg-config installed on my Ubuntu 16.04.

My questions:

- Why is the package pkg-config not installed by default?
- If I install this package: Will there be a conflict between pkg-config and whatever is used to replace it in 16.04?
- If pkg-config can cause troubles in 16.04: How can I install the wanted cpan-module in ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `pkg-config` is installed in the desktop but not in the server version of Ubuntu. That's because you are less likely compiling stuff that needs `pkg-config` on a server and most of its dependencies are installed on the desktop anyway but not on a server.

It's used in 16.04, too. If you need it on your server you can just install it.